# get a specific column data with column name "CC" from different excel sheets from different folders

Tags: vba, excel

I have 5 folders namely:

```
version1
version2
version3
version4
version5
```

each of this folders have four excel files:

```
gt
ga
ra
fe
ca
```

I want to fetch a specific column data with column name `CC` from each of this excel files into different sheets in a workbook. Data is to be fetched from all the folders into single file using VBA. Any assistance please? Thanks!

Comment: We can assist sure. What have you tried so far, and where *specifically* did you run into problems?  Please post the code you have which isn't quite working, along with any errors you're getting.  Be sure to indicate exactly which line(s) give the errors.

Comment: i havn't witten any code till now, i am thinking on how to loop into different folders and different excel workbook to get the specific column data

Comment: You know the folder and filenames, so you would use `Workbooks.Open` to open each file in turn and copy out the content you want.  There are literally hundreds of similar examples here on SO alone.  See the ones listed under "Related" on this page.

Comment: I am not aware on how to loop within folders.and files .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you are looking for.

Note that this code will look in the first row of every workbook to find the value "CC". Also note that this assumes data is on the first sheet of every workbook.

```
Sub CopyColumns()

Dim TargetWb, SourceWb As Workbook
Dim myPath, myFile, myExtension, LastRowSource, LastRowTarget As String
Dim SourceColNo, TargetColNo, RowNo, SheetNo As Long
Dim Folder, FolderArray As Variant
Dim CopyHeaders As Boolean
Set TargetWb = ActiveWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '******************************************************************************************
    ' ************************* USER VARIABLES - PLEASE CHANGE ********************************
    '******************************************************************************************

        'Set Column Index to which data will be entered on this workbook

        TargetColNo = 1

        'Set the sheet number you wish to start inserting data from

        SheetNo = 1

        'Copy header row

        CopyHeader = True

        'Set Target Folder Path which contains folders "Version1" etc

        myPath = "C:\New\"

        'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")

        myExtension = "*.xlsx"

        'Folder names to search, should you wish to change, add or remove any

        FolderArray = Array("version1", "version2", "version3", "version4", "version5")

    '******************************************************************************************
    '******************************************************************************************
    '******************************************************************************************

    'Convert Col No to Letter

    Dim TgtColLetter
    TgtColLetter = Split(Cells(1, TargetColNo).Address(True, False), "$")

        'Loop through folders

        For Each Folder In FolderArray

        'Target Path with Ending Extention

        myFile = Dir(myPath & Folder & "\" & myExtension)

        'Loop through each Excel file in folder
            Do While myFile <> ""


                'Set variable equal to opened workbook
                Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & Folder & "\" & myFile)

                'Find Column named 'CC'

                SourceColNo = WorksheetFunction.Match("CC", SourceWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:H1"), 0)
                Dim SrcColLetter
                SrcColLetter = Split(Cells(1, SourceColNo).Address(True, False), "$")

                'Get Last Row of Source Workbook
                LastRowSource = SourceWb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, SourceColNo).End(xlUp).Row

                'Get Last Row of Target Workbook and add new sheets as required
                On Error Resume Next
                LastRowTarget = TargetWb.Sheets(SheetNo).Cells(Rows.Count, TargetColNo).End(xlUp).Row
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                TargetWb.Activate
                TargetWb.Sheets.Add After:=TargetWb.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0


                If CopyHeader = False Then
                RowNo = 2
                Else
                RowNo = 1
                End If

                'Copy from Source to Target
                SourceWb.Sheets(1).Range(SrcColLetter(0) & RowNo & ":" & SrcColLetter(0) & LastRowSource).Copy _
                Destination:=TargetWb.Sheets(SheetNo).Range(TgtColLetter(0) & LastRowTarget)

                'Close Workbook
                SourceWb.Close SaveChanges:=False

                'Get next file name
                myFile = Dir

                'Move to next sheet on TargetWb
                SheetNo = SheetNo + 1
            Loop

        Next Folder

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I need to fetch only Column "CC" data, and this column name can be on between Column A -Column F.

Comment: Hi, is this column name in Row 1 of every sheet?

Comment: thank you! this code helped me, is there possibility to get the output of each source in different worksheet

Comment: Thanks @tharunthamaiah if it helped you you can upvote my answer :)   In regard to the different sheet, would you like a new sheet for every single source workbook?

Comment: Please see above answer edited @tharunthamaiah. Let me know if this does what you are needing.